# Background color and image are colliding.

Tags: html, css

Ok just to be clear this is the first time I've used this site before so I am sorry if I'm not posting this entirely correct.

Ok I'm doing this for an assignment and here is what the instructor is after "Update your alternate CSS file to: - use italics for the footer text - use a background image configured for the body - use a solid background color for the paragraphs content so that they are more readable over the background image." This is a basic HTML class and we're just learning how to put in images. The background color for the headings and the paragraphs are covering the background image and I am not sure how to fix this given what I have learned at this point any help you can provide would be very much appreciated.

```
    HTML:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <title>Two tickets please</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-alt.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <header>
        <h1>Shane&rsquo;s Travel Fan Page</h1>
    </header>
    <hr>
    <main>
        <h2>Why not just take a Staycation?</h2>
        <p>First of all let me say that staycations can be a great way to spend a little time off, however
            <br> I find being away from my home more to my liking. You can argue by definition every time
            <br> we go to work or school that we are traveling so what is the big deal? While this is technically
            <br> travel it is mechanical, souless, unless of course you pass by some great scenery every day for example
            <br> if you lived in Duluth. Travel is a great way to step away from the familiar, meet new people and learn more
            <br> about yourself. If you can find time to get away whether it be locally, across the country, or across the world,
            <br> then take the chance and make some memories. Would you like to know more? Check out: <a href="http://www.budgettravel.com"><span class="hyper">BudgetTravel.com</span></a>
        </p>
        <h2>Where have I been?</h2>
        <p>These are my most memorable destinations:</p>
        <ul>
            <li class="destination"><strong>Arizona</strong></li>
            <li class="destination"><strong>Hawaii</strong></li>
            <li class="destination"><strong>Japan</strong></li>
            <li class="destination"><strong>Malayasia</strong></li>
            <li class="destination"><strong>Mexico</strong></li>
            <li class="destination"><strong>Thailand</strong></li>
            <li class="destination"><strong>The Philippines</strong></li>
            <li class="destination"><strong>Singapore</strong></li>
        </ul>

        <p id="new">While I love traveling through the US, international travel has always been number one in my mind, plus I met my wife abroad so I am a little biased. If you are also interested in travel and want to discuss it my email is at the bottom of the page. Happy Trails!</p>
    </main>
    <footer>
<a href="mailto:shanelamb@lamb.com"><small>Email:shanelamb@lamb.com</small></a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <small>Copyright &copy; 2016 Shane Lamb</small>
      </footer>
    </body>

    </html>

    CSS: 
    body { background-color: #F0FFFF;
    color: #5B5B5B;
    background-image: url(river.jpg);
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    h1 { background-color: #43CD80;
     color: #000000;
     "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;}
    h2 { background-color: #BDFCC9;
     font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;}
    p {background-color: #CCFFFF;}
    footer { font-style: italic;
         font-size: .75em;
         text-align: left;}
    ul { list-style-type: circle;}
    .hyper {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 120%;
    .destination { color: #B8860B;}
    #new { color: #FF8C00}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I didn't understand the question right - but from what I understand from your teacher's request - The paragraphs should cover the background image so you can read the paragraph content more easily. (correct me if im wrong)

if you want to make the paragraph background color half transparent you can use rgba() as the color.
Like so -

```
  p {
    background-color: rgba(204, 255, 255, 0.7);
    color: black;
  }
```

in rgba(r,g,b,a) - the parameters are -

- r - How much red shades (0-255)
- g - How much green shades (0-255)
- b - How much blue shades (0-255)
- a - Opacity in precents (0-1)

Here is a live example - https://jsfiddle.net/g0kq073v/

Comment: Thanks for your answer the live example was helpful. To be honest I am a bit confused as to what she is looking for as we have not covered transparency yet but I feel like your example was what she wanted. I'm going to get ahold of her and ask if this is what she want. Again thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to ask for code when it is an assignment. The whole purpose is to learn. So instead of giving you the code, here is the "how to"

- identify the section you are working on in the html. So for instance if you want to do something to the paragraph text in the footer, identify the `footer` and then the `p` by putting a space in between them in the css. This is a basic specificity rule. Like this:

  footer p{
    /*something here */
  }
- In many cases you will need to identify the element with a `class` because making changes globally doesn't make sense. For instance, you will probably have many `div` elements wrapping content inside. If you do something to the `div` it will apply to all `div` elements. Not ideal. So you add a a class to the div you want to style. Like this:

  text

Now you can style that specific `div` paragraph only like this:

```
.myclass p{
   /* something here */
}
```

- In yet another common scenario, your class may be repeated on several divs but you only want to use some styles globally and some specific to some divs. This is the beauty of CSS - cascading and specificity rules. For instance you have 2 divs with equal sizes and one is red and the other is blue. You'll need to do something like this:

The CSS would look like this:

```
.box{
  /* something to be shared by both box divs */
}
.box.red{
  /* make it red*/
}
.box.blue{
  /* make it blue*/
}
```

Notice there is no space between box and red or box and blue. This means you are using both of those classes in the same div.

There are plenty of tutorials online on how to apply styles to the background and text, etc. Go to these tutorials and resources and get familiar with them

Some good resources are:

[CSS3 beginners](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/)

[Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/web)

[CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/)

[CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: I appreciate the help I have been stuck on this several days trying to figure it out. I agree with you about learning it and figuring it out for myself though I wouldn't have come here for help if I wasn't truly stuck. Thank you again for your answer!

Comment: I get that, but there are thousands of resources online with this information. To many developers here it looks like you didn't google things up first. I think you will be able to get more specific answers if you ask differently too. For example, if you are looking for how to apply background color to an element, search for that specifically and ask for help with the specific problem that is stopping you from adding the background technique you found in your search. ;)

Comment: You will probably get answers from users with low reputation but those with the highest reputations will not be encouraged to help you and they are the ones that can help you most because they have years of experience (I have 12 for instance) The reason why is because they know what is available online and what needs some brainstorming and loop finding to make it work. Makes sense? Just trying to help you ;)

Comment: I appreciate the help and your right it does look like I just came here and didn't do any sort of research. I think my poor wording on Google was to blame for me not finding what I was looking for added to the fact that what answers I did find were more advanced than what I currently have learned in class. Hopefully I won't run in to many more snags like this but so far I'm really enjoying the class. Have a great day!